# Pull System Time From Another Computer on LAN

Tags: windows, networking, lan, time, clock

I have a Windows 10 computer that has no internet connection. Whenever I power off the computer, the clock stops running, and since it has no internet connection, it cannot re-synchronize the time when I power it back on, so the clock always falls behind by however many minutes it was turned off for. I replaced the CMOS battery with a new one and it didn't change anything; it still doesn't keep the time when powered off.

I have it hooked into a LAN through ethernet cables and a network switch, and there is another computer on the LAN that does not have this problem and keeps the time correctly.

Is there some way I can tell the computer with the time problem to pull the time from the computer that doesn't have this problem? They are both Windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the computer with the working clock as a [local NTP server](https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/otlink-wo/How-to-Configure-a-Local-NTP-Server.html) and the computer which cannot keep the time as [NTP Client](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-time-servers-windows-10) of that server.